# Photoelectric effect and work function relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, photons, photoelectric-effect

[image: Graph]

Let's consider the graph above for two metals $M_1$ and $M_2$ showing relation between photocurrent and potential. First question that I want to ask here is that how do you relate  stopping potential of two metals ? from Einstein relation I know that $$K_{max}=hf-\phi$$
and when photocurrent is $0$ potential at that point is stopping potential and hence from graph $|V_2|>|V_1|$ hence $\phi_2>\phi_1$ but this wrong , why? and is there any way we can relate $f_1$ and $f_2$ ? I think here we cannot say anything because data is insufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative potential works against the $K$ of the ejected electrons. So at very high negative voltages there is no photocurrent. As the voltage moves closer to zero, we hit the point where $f_2$ produces a current. If it's able to produce a current, this means that the electrons are ejected with a high kinetic energy, and thus the work function that binds them to the metal should be lower.

As the voltage becomes less, more and more electrons from $f_2$ have enough kinetic energy to overcome the voltage and create a current. Eventually we reach $V_1$ where the $f_1$ electrons can just barely create current. These electrons must have a lower maximum kinetic energy than $f_2$, and thus a larger work function. So $\phi_1 \gt \phi_2$

I'm not exactly sure what happens when the two lines converge. Maybe the voltage is so high that random electrons are stripped from the metal. Or maybe it's that every photon that ejects an electron makes it to the other plate as current and because there's an equal number of photons the currents approach the same limit.